# Receiving database issue PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I've just set up an old script of mine which works fine on all the web hosts I've tried but one (including localhost).

Anyhow, I've set up the database and it's connected (I've tried the connection and it should work fine), though I am recieving an error that my site can not connect to the database.

I am receiving the PDOException message no matter what.

config.php

```
<?php
require "details.php";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo 'Your website can not connect to the database';
}
```

details.php

```
<?php

$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'myuser';
$password = 'mypassword';
$database = 'mydatabase';

define('DB_NAME', 'mydatabase');
define('DB_USER', 'myuser');
define('DB_PASS', 'mypassord');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

I've come to the conclusion that it must be one of those codes that it must be something to do with the above code.

I have tried this code below to make sure the PDO extention is enabled and yes it is.

```
<?php

if (!defined('PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME')) {
    echo 'PDO unavailable';
}
elseif (defined('PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME')) {
    echo 'PDO available';
}
```

Any idea, maybe why?

Comment: So what is the exception message? `echo $e->getMessage();` in the `catch` block.

Comment: @lonesomeday "could not find driver"

Comment: So there you go. The PDO extension isn't available in your localhost environment. You need to edit your php.ini file and remove the comment beside the PDO extension

Comment: It sounds like you haven't got the `pdo_mysql` driver installed/enabled on this server, then. You need to install/enable it.

Comment: Is it possible for myself to do it on a shared hosting?

Comment: @user3523090 You should contact your hosting provider. It sounds like they've got a pretty funky setup if they have MySQL installed but not `pdo_mysql`. It's worth checking, by the way: do `var_dump(extension_loaded('pdo_mysql'));` to confirm that this is indeed the problem.

Comment: @lonesomeday recieve bool(false), also what would be the best thing to say to convince my hosting to install it?

Comment: @user3523090 Money. (joke)

Comment: @user3523090 I'd say that it's a pretty standard feature in modern PHP development and that this is the first time you've encountered a server that doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of that catch stuff.

Leave only three lines in this file

```
<?php
require "details.php";
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
```

and see what does it say, either on screen or in log, according to site settings.

Comment: Can debugging stuff also be posted as an answer or maybe you plan to edit it once the OP comes back with a response? Not the downvoter btw

Comment: Why down vote this as an answer, i'm curious- what if this actually does fix the issue?

Comment: Now it says: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'

Comment: @CoderDojo Because it's both the wrong way to get the exception message and it's advice on debugging, not an answer to the question.